# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_23" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(50, 28, 28)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image]

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_23" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(50, 28, 28)

Comment: Your input data (x_train) must have the same shape as the shape as the input shape you defined for your model. Your data is 28, 28, but you defined your model with 784.

Comment: 784 = 28 * 28, like the total pixels of image. If I change it 28, 28 I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data and model must have the same shape!

If your data is `(anything, 28, 28)`, then your model's input shape MUST be `(28,28)`. You cannot use 784.

If your model is `input_shape=(784,)` or `input_dim=784`, your data MUST be `(anything, 784)`.